# Maximize sum of exponentials with constraints to their constants

Tags: optimization, exponential-function, maxima-minima

I have the following function:

$$g(t) = c_1 \cdot e^{-4t}+c_2 \cdot e^{-t}$$

and the constants that multiply them are:

$$c_1 = {\frac {16+a_{{0}}-4\,a_{{1}}}{-4+b_{{0}}}}$$

$$c_2 = -{\frac {a_{{0}}-b_{{0}}a_{{1}}+{b_{{0}}}^{2}}{-4+b_{{0}}}}$$

Also, I know beforehand that $a_0 \in [1, 9]$, $a_1 \in [-6,-2]$ and $b_0 \in [1,3]$.

I would like to know the maximum value that $|g(t)|$ could reach (it is important to highlight that $t$ is time, therefore can only be non-negative).

Sorry if this is a very easy optimization problem, but I am not very used to these techniques. Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: I previously had a typo (double minus, which equals plus, before the 2nd term of the numerator of c2). That has now been corrected. My earlier comments were based on solving the problem which had the typo.

The max value of $|g(t)|$, as well as $g(t)$, is $15.347792$, and is achieved at $t = 0.564865, a_0 = 9, a_1 = -6, b_0 = 3$, which produces corresponding $c_1 = -49, c_2 = 36$.

How do I know?  I ran the "rigorous" numerical global optimizer YALMIP's BMIBNB and some other checks.

Comment: Sorry, but I think the maximal value of $c_1 + c_2$ is 13 ($c_1+c_2 = a_1 - b_0 - 4$). Moreover, how can I guarantee that there will be no combination of the exponentials at $t > 0$ that will result in a larger value than 13?

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo. $c_1 + c_2 = 49$ was missing the minus sign before the 49, but the answer is correct, with that typo fixed.  Do you really want to maximize |g(t)|, which is what you wrote and I did, or do you want to maximize g(t)?  Indeed, the maximum of g(t) does not occur at t = 0, but rather at t = 0.7993, with maximum value of g(t) = 4.0468.

Comment: Maximum of g(t) mentioned at the end of my preceding comment occurs at $a_0 = 9, a_1 = -2, b_0 = 3$ , which produces $c_1 = -33, c_2 = 12$. So if you are trying to maximize g(t) and if your upper bounds are actually fuzzy rather than solid, then the  maximum value of g would be affected, and you would have to give the matter more consideration. Of course the bounds drive the answer for maximizing |g(t)| as well.

Comment: Sorry, but I am still in doubt. You are right, what I want is the maximum value of $|g(t)|$. And as far as I understood, you are saying that the maximum value of $|g(t)| = 49$, which happens at $t=0.7993$ and $c_1 + c_2 = -13$, correct? Thanks!

Comment: No, you are mixing up the solutions to max |g(t)| and max g(t). The max value of |g(t)| = 49, and occurs at $a_1 = -6, b_0 = 3, t = 0$, which produces corresponding $c_1 + c_2 = -49$.

Comment: I have plotted $|g(t)|$ with $a_1 = -6$, $b_0 = 3$ and multiple values for $a_1$, and the max value of the function was $15.348$ at $t=0.582$. All the values at $t=0$ were equal to $13$.

Comment: Sorry. I previously had a typo (double minus, which equals plus, before the 2nd term of the numerator of c2). That has now been corrected. My earlier comments were based on solving the problem which had the typo.